# How can I check if sentences in array contains exact words in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, algorithm

For example, I have the following arrays:

```
var reviews = ["Skating is good in Austria", 
"I loved the Spanish food, it had so many varieties and 
it was super super delicious. The price was a little bit high but 
it was worth it. People who don't like spicy food might need 
to think twice as it could be a little bit problematic for them.", 
"I didn’t like the Indian food!", 
"People were really friendly, I enjoyed being there."]

var words = ["Skating", "Food", "Climbing"]
```

Now I want to check, if these reviews contain one of my words.

The challenge is: One or more reviews can contain these words and I want to find these reviews, add them into an array and print.

For this I do:

```
var arr = [String]()

for review in reviews {
    for word in words {
        if review.containsString(word) {
            arr.append(review)
        }
    }
    print(arr)
}
```

but that prints only the first sentence:

```
["Skating is good in Austria"]
```

So, I want to check, if one or more reviews, contains on of these words from the array, then to put ALL these matched reviews into an `arr` array.

Can anyone help me with it? I'm confused why it take just one review and stop after

Comment: Your code works. If you think you should get a match also for "Food" then no, because of the capitalization. "Food" != "food"

Comment: `for word in words { arr.appendContentsOf(reviews.filter({ $0.containsString(word) })) }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the `print` sentence out of your loop.

Like this:

```
var arr = [String]()

for review in reviews {
    for word in words {
        if review.containsString(word) {
            arr.append(review)
        }
    }
}
print(arr)
```

Also, if you don't want to get duplicate reviews, I would use a `set` instead of an array: `var arr = Set<String>()`

Also, it's probably the case that you need a case insensitive string comparison. Change `Food` by `food` in your words array and try again.

To get a full case insensitive loop working, try this:

```
for review in reviews {
    for word in words {
        if review.lowercaseString.containsString(word.lowercaseString) {
            arr.append(review)
        }
    }
}
print(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want ignore case with string just try like this way using `filter` method of `array`, it will reduce your code of looping.

```
var predicateString = [String]()
for word in words {
    predicateString(String(format:"SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@", word)
}
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%@",predicateString.joined(separator: " || "));
let filteredArray = reviews.filter { predicate.evaluateWithObject($0) };
print(filteredArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Functional Programming

First of all lets create an array of lowercase keywords (I assume you want case insensitive matching).

```
let keywords = words.map { $0.lowercaseString }
```

Next

```
let matchingSentences = reviews.filter { sentence  in
    let lowerCaseSentence = sentence.lowercaseString
    return keywords.contains { keyword in sentence.rangeOfString(keyword) != nil }
}
```

Result

```
matchingSentences.forEach { print($0) }

Skating is good in Austria
I loved the Spanish food, it had so many varieties and it was super super delicious. The price was a little bit high but it was worth it. People who don't like spicy food might need to think twice as it could be a little bit problematic for them.
I didn’t like the Indian food!
```

### Shorter version

```
let res = reviews.filter { sentence in keywords.contains { sentence.lowercaseString.rangeOfString($0) != nil } }
```